Null Reference Exception in Blazor when Navigating Directly to Page
I am working on a Server/Client Blazor app using Interactive Web Assembly. I have a page that lists some objects (Tenants), and when clicking on those objects, it navigates to a page with the ID of the object as a parameter in the Uri path.
/tenants/ -> /tenants/{Id}
When navigating via clicking on the link, everything works properly and I have no issues. However, if I directly enter the Uri to the specific object in the browser, I get a generic NullReferenceException which appears to be generating from my Server's DbContext.OnConfiguring() method based on going through breakpoints, but on the "no code to show" page. Below are the relevant code snippets (some code removed for brevity). I feel like this is a lack of knowledge on my part with respect to Interactive Web Assembly as it just doesn't make sense to me otherwise. Any help would be appreciated.

Single Tenant Page (Client)
@page "/tenants/{Id}"
@inject HttpClient httpClient

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public string Id { get; set; } = null!;

  TenantClientService tenantService = null!;

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
      tenantService = new TenantClientService(httpClient);
      targetTenant = await tenantService.GetTenantAsync(Guid.Parse(Id)) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Tenant with ID {Id} not found"); // <--- Throwing here
  }
}

tenantService (Client)
internal async Task<Tenant?> GetTenantAsync(Guid id) {
    Logger.LogInformation("Getting tenant with id {id}", id);
    Tenant? tenant = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Tenant>($"{_endpoint}/{id}"); // <--- Throwing here
    if(tenant is null) {
        Logger.LogError("Failed to get tenant with id {id}", id);
    }
    return tenant;
}

Controller (Server)
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid id) {
    Tenant? tenant = await tenantRepository.GetTenantByIdAsync(id); // <--- Throwing here
    if (tenant is null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(tenant);
}

Repo (Server)
public async Task<Tenant> GetTenantByIdAsync(Guid id) {
    Logger.LogInformation("Getting tenant with id {id}", id);
    Tenant? tenant = await Context.Tenants.FindAsync(id); // <--- Throwing here
    if (tenant is null) {
        Logger.LogError("Tenant with id {id} not found", id);
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id), "Tenant not found");
    }
    return tenant;
}

DbContext (Server)
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) {
    options.UseNpgsql(  // <--- Seems to be throwing somewhere here.
            new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder {
                Host = config.Host,
                Port = config.Port,
                Database = config.Database,
                Username = config.Username,
                Password = config.Password
            }.ConnectionString
        )
}

I tried navigating to the page via direct URL (i.e. https://localhost:7190/tenants/48277ddd-342e-4a99-b683-cce1c953f564) and expected to get the same result as navigating via the link from the tenant list, but instead got a NullReferenceException.
Edit 1
Call Stack:
Symphony.Client.dll!Symphony.Client.Pages.TenantPage.BuildRenderTree.AnonymousMethod__0_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(int sequence, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment fragment)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.PageTitle.BuildTitleRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder builder) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment renderFragment, out System.Exception renderFragmentException)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(int componentId, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment renderFragment)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView parameters)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int componentId, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView initialParameters)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.BeginRenderingComponent(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IComponent component, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView initialParameters)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.EndpointHtmlRenderer.RenderEndpointComponent(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext, System.Type rootComponentType, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView parameters, bool waitForQuiescence)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.InvokeAsync.AnonymousMethod__10_0((System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder completion, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> asyncAction) state) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.InvokeWithThisAsCurrentSyncCtxThenSetResult<(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)>(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder completion, System.Action<(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)> callback, (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>) state)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.SendIfQuiescedOrElsePost<(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)>(System.Action<(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)> callback, (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>) state) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.InvokeAsync(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> asyncAction)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.AntiforgeryMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
    Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    [Resuming Async Method] 
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<InvokeAsync>d__7>.ExecutionContextCallback(object s)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<InvokeAsync>d__7>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<InvokeAsync>d__7>.MoveNext()    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object continuationObject)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon> task, System.__Canon result)    Unknown
    [Completed] Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.GetScriptTag(string requestId, bool isHttps, string hostUrl)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<GetScriptTag>d__8>.ExecutionContextCallback(object s)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<string>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<GetScriptTag>d__8>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<GetScriptTag>d__8>.MoveNext()  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object continuationObject)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon> task, System.__Canon result)    Unknown
    [Completed] System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync.__Core|83_0(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, bool disposeCts, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, System.Threading.CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d>.ExecutionContextCallback(object s)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d>.MoveNext()    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object continuationObject)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon> task, System.__Canon result)    Unknown
    [Completed] System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4>.ExecutionContextCallback(object s)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread) Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4>.MoveNext()  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object continuationObject)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon> task, System.__Canon result)    Unknown
    [Completed] System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.<SendAsyncCore>d__10>.ExecutionContextCallback(object s)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.<SendAsyncCore>d__10>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread) Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.<SendAsyncCore>d__10>.MoveNext()  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object continuationObject)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon> task, System.__Canon result)    Unknown
    [Completed] System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, bool doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__89>.ExecutionContextCallback(object s)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__89>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread) Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__89>.MoveNext()  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask)    Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object continuationObject)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>.TrySetResult(System.__Canon result)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon> task, System.__Canon result)    Unknown
    [Completed] System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsync>d__57>.ExecutionContextCallback(object s)  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread, System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsync>d__57>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread) Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsync>d__57>.ExecuteFromThreadPool(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread) Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart() Unknown
    [Async Call Stack]  
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IHttpApplication<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context> application)    Unknown
    [Async] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IHttpApplication<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context> application)   Unknown

Edit 2
After selecting "Show External Code" in the Call Stack of Visual Studio, I was able to isolate the place where the exception is being thrown:
TenantPage.BuildRenderTree
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
{
    __builder.OpenComponent<PageTitle>(0);
    __builder.AddAttribute(1, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)delegate(RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)
    {
        __builder2.AddContent(2, targetTenant.Name); // <-- Throwing here
    });
    __builder.CloseComponent();
    __builder.AddMarkupContent(3, "\r\n\r\n");
/...
}


What’s the call stack on the exception?

The bottom of the stack is usually the most informative - where the problem started. Maybe put it in a gist or other online place and add a link to the question?

@stuartd I have edited the answer to include the call stack.

I see it, thanks. It doesn’t look very helpful?

I wonder if https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier would help in this case. I see now you’ve added comments like ‘throwing here’ in your code snippets, if you add breakpoints can you see the exception ‘happening’?

Another possibility - have you tried with the debugger set to ‘break when exception is thrown’ for all exceptions?

I had added breakpoints to all of these places, however after selecting "Show External Code" in the Call Stack, it's showing me the actual place where the exception is happening. I'll have to dig further into this when I can be back at my machine and I will add additional context to the question.

The issue ended up being in an omitted part of the code in the TenantPage:
@* ... *@
<PageTitle>@targetTenant.Name</PageTitle>
@* ... *@

Using a null-conditional resolves the issue (thanks @LoneSpawn):
@* ... *@
<PageTitle>@targetTenant?.Name</PageTitle>
@* ... *@

I can only attribute this to some kind of race condition with rendering versus getting data from the Server API, as it worked well when traversing through hyperlinks on the app.
Thanks to @stuartd for putting me on the right track.

Cleaner using null-conditional: <PageTitle>@targetTenant?.Name</PageTitle>
